# What is some pure math news website by a publisher?

Tags: reference-request, big-list, publishing

Why aren't there be any pure math website by a publisher?

I google a lot and resulting only applied math news or math journal that is difficult and  inaccessible even to advanced reader

I am looking for new york times style news website but specifically for pure math only

In other word, i want the style to be in newspaper format that omit all of math equations.

Comment: @skullpatrol - But that website is all about applied math without much pure math news.

Comment: @skullpatrol - Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MAA [Math in the News](http://www.maa.org/news/math-news)

AMS [Math in the Media](http://www.ams.org/news/math-in-the-media/math-in-the-media)

Answer (score 4):

The terrance tao blog is great,  http://terrytao.wordpress.com

A lot of advance topics, but also lots of links to other more common topics!

check it out,

Comment: But it isn't by a publisher or in word-written format...

Comment: Also it is too technical

Comment: Hmm alright, sorry about that. Not sure what your looking for, maybe if your at a university itd be best to check out some journals? Can you be more specific what/why you are looking for?

Comment: Do you have any clue right now?

Comment: You aren't communicating very effectively.